# How to get base64 encoded contents for an ImageReader?

Tags: java, image, htmlunit

How do I read an image into a base64 encoded string by its `ImageReader`?

Here's example source code using HtmlUnit. I want to get the base64 String of `img`:

```
  WebClient wc = new WebClient();
  wc.setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
  wc.setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
  HtmlPage p = wc.getPage("http://flickr.com");
  HtmlImage img = (HtmlImage) p.getByXPath("//img").get(3);
  System.out.println(img.getImageReader().getFormatName());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The HtmlUnit's [`HtmlImage#getImageReader()`](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/HtmlImage.html#getImageReader%28%29) returns [`javax.imageio.ImageReader`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageReader.html) which is part of standard [Java 2D API](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/2d/index.html). You can get an [`BufferedImage`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) out of it which you in turn can write to an `OutputStream` of any flavor using [`ImageIO#write()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#write%28java.awt.image.RenderedImage,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.OutputStream%29).

The [Apache Commons Codec](http://commons.apache.org/codec/) has a [`Base64OutputStream`](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64OutputStream.html) which you can just decorate your `OutputStream` with.

```
HtmlImage img = (HtmlImage) p.getByXPath("//img").get(3);
ImageReader imageReader = img.getImageReader();
BufferedImage bufferedImage = imageReader.read(0);
String formatName = imageReader.getFormatName();
ByteArrayOutputStream byteaOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
Base64OutputStream base64Output = new base64OutputStream(byteaOutput);
ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, formatName, base64output);
String base64 = new String(byteaOutput.toByteArray());
```

Or if you want to write it to file directly:

```
// ...
FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream("/base64.txt");
Base64OutputStream base64Output = new base64OutputStream(fileOutput);
ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, formatName, base64output);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what exactly you want.

But what about creating your own Reader (see javax.imageio.stream.ImageInputStreamImpl), containing the Base64-stuff?
Maybe this [external free Base64Encoder](http://www.source-code.biz/base64coder/java/) can help you out.

Something that could be used like this in the end?

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient(); 
wc.setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false); 
wc.setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false); 

HtmlPage p = wc.getPage("http://flickr.com"); 
HtmlImage img = (HtmlImage) p.getByXPath("//img").get(3); 

MyBase64EncodingReader reader = new MyBase64EncodingReader(img);
System.out.println(reader.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use one of the [encodeBase64 methods](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html)

from [apache commons codec](http://commons.apache.org/codec/).

and create a string from the resulting byte array using the String(bytes[]) constructor.